# PFQueryTableViewController getting possible error

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I have a question regarding how one would intercept an error message on a `PFQueryTableViewController`. Basically, I would like to override a method in the `PFQueryTableViewController` to allow for me to display custom error alerts if there were a problem executing the query. Does anyone know how I would perform such behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, here's the method to override:

```
- (void)objectsDidLoad:(nullable NSError *)error;
```

In your implementation, you can check if there was an error and responded as you'd like.

Note: you should [super objectsDidLoad:] if you override it.

[Source: Parse Docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQueryTableViewController(im)objectsDidLoad:)